# showing console warning or error into the scrren

Tags: firebase, react-native, validation, formik, yup

I am using React Native, firebase. I have a login component that has an email and password field. It is validated using formik and yup. Here is my code link using expo snack.

[Link of Login Components](https://snack.expo.io/@mamun_121/testing_snack)

It is working properly if correct credentials are provided. However, if I provided the wrong password, any warning is not showing, however, in the console, there is an error message. How can I show those error messages on the screen or below the password field?

[image: console errors]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach:

First of all, we want to have a
`import React, {useState} from 'react'`

on the top of your component add
`[loginErrorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')`

now in the return of your function component you want to add a text field like this

`<Text>{loginErrorMessage}</Text>`

at last in your catch statement of the handleSignup function add
`setErrorMessage(error.message)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have followed your steps, however, it's not working.